# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "filepath" is denied

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, storage

I encountered a problem of writing files on sd card. Here I open a stream to write data in it.

```
public Stream GetStreamWrite(string filePath) // filePath = "/storage/B4AD-3FC1/Xml/kek.xml"
{ // B4AD-3FC1 - name of sd card
    var write = File.OpenWrite(filePath); // Here I get UnauthorizedAccessException  Access to the path is denied
    return write;
}
```

What could be the reason of this issue?

Exception Stack Trace

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/B4AD-3FC1/Xml/kek.xml" is denied.
                                           at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0027b] in <a1809d1a7c0741e8b5f4d5285e25edcf>:0 
                                           at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <a1809d1a7c0741e8b5f4d5285e25edcf>:0 
                                             at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
                                           at System.IO.File.OpenWrite (System.String path) [0x00000] in <a1809d1a7c0741e8b5f4d5285e25edcf>:0 
                                           at Dct.Droid.AndroidDataStorage.GetStreamWrite (System.String filePath) [0x00000] in <06e2b936a8ac46408294407357c72652>:0 
                                           at Dct.GoodStorage.GenerateLocalFile (System.String dir, System.String fileName, System.String format, System.String prefix) [0x0029d] in <659575193ffe49819bcb0803dc16e2a1>:0
```

P.S. I've tried File.Create(.NET) and File.CreateNewFile(Java) but both return the same exception.

Comment: SD cards have a lock trigger. Maybe the card is locked.

Comment: From docs: "The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error."

Comment: do you have the required permission (android manifest) to perform IO operations on that path?

Comment: @TobiasWürth yea, i was testing it on KitKat and I got the same exception

Comment: @GryphG Reading from this sd card works well

Comment: Yes. But nowadays Google does not want you to write on the sd card using the file system. They placed a content provider between the card and your app. Its time you learn to use the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: Why did you need write date to `"/storage/B4AD-3FC1/` folder?